# Why does Windows tell me that .dll file is not found when I just use the static .lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, static-libraries

I think I have an understanding problem and I'd be very glad if somebody finally explained it to me...

I'm developing a Win32 application (.exe) which uses my own static library (.lib). The library depends on another *static* library (libxml2 for Windows in fact).

What I did:

- I added the libxml include directory into my .lib project "VC++ Directories"->"Include Directories".
- I built my lib, the build was successful, and .lib file appeared in my Output folder.
- I created a console application project and wrote some code which uses the .lib functions (which in turn use libxml functions). My lib project was added as a reference into the app project using "Framework and References"->"Add New Reference".
- I tried to build the application and got linker errors - this is OK, because I forgot to add libxml2.lib to my application via "Linker"->"Input"->"Additional Dependencies". So I added libxml2.lib to the dependencies and the path to it to "VC++ Directories"->"Library Directories".
  I rebuilt the application and the build was successful. But when I try to start my .exe an error appears. It says: "The application has failed to start because libxml2.dll. Reinstalling the application may fix blah blah".

So why does my .exe require libxml2.dll? I want to use libxml2 only as a static library.
All experiments were done with debug configuration settings.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `libxml2` is built as a static library? Even when building a DLL a library (i.e. a `.lib` file) is generated to act as a kind of proxy between your application and the DLL.

Comment: Just to add on to Joachim's comment, the name for this type of .lib file is an "import library".

Comment: I downloaded my libxml from the Internet and the "lib" folder contained 3 files: libxml2.lib, libxml2_a.lib and libxml2_a_dll.lib. I used libxml2.lib, I thought it is the right one. I will test two other options right now.

Comment: It seems that libxml2_a.lib was the correct one. But it now requires more dependencies by itself. E. g. it needs _libiconv_open which, as I understand, belongs to libiconv library. I'm now trying to find the correct libiconv.lib.

Comment: Thanks everybody, everything work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your lib path for the DLL version of the lib appears prior to the static lib version.